# Show NULL Value And Space As 1 entry

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running a SQL Query but the problem I am hitting is that the entry's are NULL or SPACE (So two seperate values) Is there a way short of an update query to show NULL And Space as one value?  And emergencyContact returns either NULL or just a space.  So I am getting 2 rows returned for each employee Name.  How can I set the Null and space to return in one row?

```
Select Name, emergencyContact
FROM employeeDatabase
Group By Name, emergencyContact
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` Nulls to the same ' ' and group by same:

```
Select Name, ISNULL(emergencyContact, ' ') AS emergencyContact
FROM employeeDatabase
Group By Name, ISNULL(emergencyContact, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` to combine `null` and `''`

```
Select Name, 
       case when emergencyContact = '' 
            then null 
            else emergencyContact 
       end as emergencyContact 
FROM employeeDatabase
Group By Name, 
         case when emergencyContact = '' 
              then null 
              else emergencyContact 
         end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `EmergencyContact` CTE in my response  is just to generate data on the fly. You would just use the `SELECT` query.

This will display all values as `NULL` if there are multiple records and they are `''`, `' '`, or `NULL`. If there is an actual value in the set as well, then it will display the value and do away with the empty values.

```
;WITH EmergencyContact (Name, EmergencyContact) AS (
    SELECT 'Tim', 'Felicia' UNION
    SELECT 'Tim', ''        UNION
    SELECT 'Tim', ' '       UNION 
    SELECT 'Tim', NULL      UNION 
    SELECT 'Jim', 'Tim'     UNION
    SELECT 'Joe', ''        UNION 
    SELECT 'Jackie', NULL   UNION 
    SELECT 'Jerry', ' '     UNION 
    SELECT 'Jerry', NULL 
)

SELECT Name
     , EmergencyContact = MAX(NULLIF(NULLIF(EmergencyContact, ''), ' '))
FROM EmergencyContact 
GROUP BY Name
```

If you want to display some other value in place of `NUL`L, then you can wrap the calculated field in an `ISNULL()` function. In the following, I display `NOCONTACT` in place of empty values.

```
;WITH EmergencyContact (Name, EmergencyContact) AS (
    SELECT 'Tim', CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'Felicia') UNION
    SELECT 'Tim', '' UNION
    SELECT 'Tim', ' ' UNION 
    SELECT 'Tim', NULL UNION 
    SELECT 'Jim', 'Tim' UNION
    SELECT 'Joe', '' UNION 
    SELECT 'Jackie', NULL UNION 
    SELECT 'Jerry', ' ' UNION 
    SELECT 'Jerry', NULL 
)

SELECT Name
     , EmergencyContact = ISNULL(MAX(NULLIF(NULLIF(EmergencyContact, ''), ' ')), 'NOCONTACT')
FROM EmergencyContact 
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COLASCE` or `CONCAT` or `ISNULL`

I would chose `COLASCE(emergencyContact,' ')` insetad of `emergencyContact`; it is more beautiful than IFs and CASEs and because of this:

> ```
> DECLARE
> @x AS VARCHAR(3) = NULL,
> @y AS VARCHAR(10) = '1234567890';
> SELECT COALESCE(@x, @y) AS [COALESCE], ISNULL(@x, @y) AS [ISNULL];
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> COALESCE    ISNULL
> ----------  ------
> 1234567890  123
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (which is pretty much exactly the same as StuartLC's answer) is to use NULLIF() instead of ISNULL()

```
Select Name, NULLIF(emergencyContact, ' ') AS emergencyContact
FROM employeeDatabase
Group By Name, NULLIF(emergencyContact, ' ');
```

It follows exactly the same logic and achieves much the same thing, just the other way round, rather than returning an single space string if the value is NULL, it returns NULL if there is only a single space in the emergencyContact.

Obviously it's a bit less reliable (unless you can guarantee that all the entries without a number are either NULL or a single space (not 2,3,4 spaces etc) but I thought I'd chime in anyway as it's just a preference of mine to return NULL if there is no usable data in a column rather than return a random string of spaces if the value is NULL.